# Vector Library: differences between .begin(), .rbegin(), cbegin(), crbegin()

Tags: c++, vector

I am not understanding the differences between

1. .begin() and .cbegin()
2. .rbegin() and .crbegin()

I usually use only .begin() and .end()

Comment: One version gives you the `const_iterator` (`cbegin`, `crbegin`) - you can't modify elements with it - and the other pair gives you an iterator which allows modification. Const versions help to enforce const-correctness.

Comment: `c` stands for `const`, so it returns a `const_iterator`, `r` stands for reverse, so it returns a `reverse_iterator`, the combination of both returns a `const_reverse_iterator`.

Comment: The entries [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) are fairly clear.

Comment: When you read the documentation, which part is unclear?

Comment: This is where [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) comes in and it's something you should refer to *often*.

Comment: ok, i will take a look on that website.

Comment: but i still don't understand the utility of cbegin()

Comment: @ManuelCarlucci _"I don't understand"_ is not a question that is handled well by Stack Overflow.  It is arguably not a question at all.  You seem to be looking for a book or a tutor.  Are you really asking what the difference is?  Or are you asking what the utility is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `constexpr iterator begin() noexcept;`

  Returns an iterator that when dereferenced returns a reference to a non-`const` (mutable) element.
- `constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept;`

  Returns an iterator that when dereferenced returns a reference to a `const` (immutable) element.
- `constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept;`

  See `cbegin()`. This `begin()` is an overload that is selected when `begin()` is called and the `vector` is in `const` context.

  Example:

  ```
  void foo(std::vector<int> const& v) {
      auto it = v.begin(); // uses the last `begin()` because `v` is `const`
  }
  ```

The `r` versions are the *reverse* versions of the above, making it possible to iterate from the back of the `vector` to the front.

Comment: Ok I understood, but why do we use a const iterator? Can I use begin() instead of cbegin()?

Comment: @ManuelCarlucci You can almost always use `begin()` and it will select the correct overload. The `const_iterator` is needed the ensure that the elements in the `vector` are not changed when the `vector` is `const`. If you dereference a `const_iterator` and try to assign a value, like  `*it = 10;`, you will get a compilation error.

Comment: @ManuelCarlucci You're welcome!